# UICollectionView's background is a screenshot of the initial position of the scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

This seems like a weird bug and I have adapted the code to see the bug better. By default the background color of my UICollectionView seems to be .systemBackground, but when I set it to .clear, instead of having a clear background, I have a "ghost" of the starting position of the first items in the scroll as a abckground. What could be happening?

[image: The bug.]

**The functions of the UICollectionView protocol:**

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LineCell", for: indexPath) as! LineCell
    cell.changeSize(indexPath.row)
    cell.text.text = String(indexPath.row)

    
    return cell
           
}
```

**How I'm adding the view:**

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 80)

numberPicker = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

secondsControlHolder.addSubview(numberPicker!)
numberPicker?.delegate = delegate
numberPicker?.dataSource = delegate

numberPicker?.register(LineCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "LineCell")

numberPicker?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
numberPicker?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
numberPicker?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
numberPicker?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
numberPicker?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
numberPicker?.backgroundColor = .clear
numberPicker?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
numberPicker?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
numberPicker?.isPagingEnabled = false



numberPicker?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (delegate.view.frame.size.width)/2, bottom: 0, right: (delegate.view.frame.size.width)/2)



let arrow = UIView()
let arrowTriangle = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.up.fill"))

secondsControlHolder.addSubview(arrow)
secondsControlHolder.addSubview(arrowTriangle)

arrow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
arrow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
arrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
arrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
arrow.backgroundColor = .label
arrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
arrow.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

arrowTriangle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
arrowTriangle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrow.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
arrowTriangle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondsControlHolder.bottomAnchor, constant: -130).isActive = true
arrowTriangle.tintColor = .label
arrowTriangle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 23).isActive = true
arrowTriangle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

**The LineCell class:**

```
import UIKit

class LineCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let lineHolder = UIView()
    let text = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        text.text = "test"
        text.textColor = .white
        lineHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lineHolder.addSubview(text)
        text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        text.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineHolder.topAnchor).isActive = true
        text.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineHolder.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        text.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        text.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lineHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        addSubview(lineHolder)
        

//        layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 1)
//           setupLineHolder()
  
       }
    
    
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    

    func setupLineHolder(){

        lineHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 80)
        

        
        lineHolder.backgroundColor = .label
  
//        setupLine()
      
    }
    
    func changeSize(_ index: Int){
        if index % 5 == 0 {
            lineHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 80)
            lineHolder.backgroundColor = .label
            
        }else{
            lineHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: 50, height: 50)
            lineHolder.backgroundColor = .label.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Check that the code that instantiates your UICollectionView and adds it as a subview (the second code block in your question) is only being called once.  It looks to me like it is being called twice (or more) so you have two UICollectionViews on top of each other, so when you scroll the top one you see the cells of the one below it.

Comment: I thought that at first and tried looking into it but didn't find anything. I looked at it again and saw I was setting up the whole "bottom area" twice, not only the UICollectionView. Thank you for your help. You're right, everything in the bottom was being setup twice on top of each other.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was calling setupControlsArea() twice. It wasn't just the UICollectionView that was duplicated, but the whole controls area view.